# Has I constructed LSTM model in a right way in Keras?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, keras

Here's a [description](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.01907.pdf) of a model I'd like to get:

> A vanilla LSTM model with similar size as our model. Specifically, a
>   two-layer sacked LSTM is  constructed,  with  128  and  32  hidden 
>   states,  respectively, followed by a fully connected layer for the
>   final output. This neural network also takes 28 days as input, and predicts the next day.

```
# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=train_X.shape)) % 28 days
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=128)) % 128 units for previous layer
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks okay as long as the input shape is correct.  `input_shape` is `(number_steps, dimension_features)`, so in this case it would be `(28, dim_feat)`.  If `dim_feat` is not 1, then you would also need to change the dimension of the output of the Dense layer to be `dim_feat`.